# socket.io на серверной части проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, charset

1. OS: windows
2. IDE: PhpStorm

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с кодировкой.
На стороне клиента проблем нет, если вывести в консоль передаваемый username и room, все отображается корректно, но в терминале сервера белиберда. Сам файл server.js в формате UTF-8. Причем такое поведение только в событии **joinRoom** в файле server.js, в событии **chatMessage** кириллица обрабатывается правильно. Почему такое происходит(ниже пояснение в комментариях)?

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "dev": "nodemon server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

chat.html в него подключен **main.js**

```
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

**main.js** - Клиент

```
var username = 'Андрей';
var room = 'it-dept';

const chatForm = document.getElementById('chat-form');
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

//Join chatRoom
socket.emit('joinRoom',{username,room});
console.log(username,room);// вывод: Андрей it-dept



//Message submit
chatForm.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    //get message text
    const msg = e.target.elements.msg.value;

    //Emitting message to server
    socket.emit('chatMessage',msg);

});
```

вывод в консоль браузера: Андрей it-dept

**server.js**

```
io.on('connection', socket => {

    console.log('New Client connected...' + socket.id);

    socket.on('joinRoom', ({username, room}) => {
        console.log('Подсоединился:',username); //Вывод: Подсоединился: Ð Ð½Ð´Ñ ÐµÐ¹
        const user = userJoin(socket.id, username, room); //pushes connected  users in array 
        socket.join(user.room);
    });


    socket.on('chatMessage', (msg) => {
        const user = getCurrentUser(socket.id);//returns users data by socket.id 

      //sending message to cliens for output to DOM  
      io.to(user.room).emit('message', formatMessage(user.username, msg));

        console.log(user.username,user.room,msg); //причем тут нормально все, вывод: корректный, кириллица отображается правильно
    });
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "dev": "nodemon server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: а какие заголовки передаются с сервера на запросе страницы? и какие заголовки на upgrade-соединения до web-сокета?

Comment: Если подскажите как посмотреть такую информацию или уточните, буду признателен. Все через localhost гуляет. В браузере в network, при переходе на страницу где идет подключение к сокету (io.connect("http://localhost:3000")), создается десяток соединений со множеством заголовков. Могу выложить чат если есть желание посмотреть что происходит.

Comment: Если нажать в браузере Ctrl+Shift+I или Command+Option+I на маке, то появится DevTools. На вкладке Network можно обновить страницу и после соединения выбрать нужные запросы, нажать по имени файла правой кнопкой мыши, и выбрать в меню *Копировать в HAR*

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ZR7jgkO.png там курсор стоит на cURL, но несколькими пунктами ниже есть HAR

Comment: До конца не уверен то или не то скопировал  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MwQyur4cmDD-5Ax9fKHrFQHYlZDTBQ4P/view?usp=sharing

Comment: то что нужно! те запросы с `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8` в них можно поменять тип `text/plain` на что-нибудь еще вроде `application/octet-stream` или другое? И еще замечено одно место где нет пробела между точкой с запятой и кодировкой:  `Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8` именно там mime-type определился как `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` вместо `text/plain`, а кодировка осталась по умолчанию выбора системы.

Comment: Что может вызывать такое поведение? попробовал var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', document.location, false);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'utf-8');
request.send(null);
request.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase(); не помогло, почему в одном событии проблемы с кодировкой а в другом нет. Хожу вокруг да около, совсем ума не приложу где что исправить нужно.

Answer (score 0):

В результате все оказалось просто.
На клиентской части использовал версию

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Изменил на

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.1/socket.io.slim.min.js" integrity="sha512-tj7TsH/mhgmfzJFXDAyYrVZbGz1tjT6/eglLxP5S7wvHz4XkTWqST0Ldx+oEWyre43PU0hlncsxCh+1u81QW9A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```